# Using a crate in a Cargo project errors with "maybe a missing extern crate"

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I started learning Rust today, but I am stuck at [this step](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html). I want use the rand crate in my project, so I updated my `Cargo.toml` as suggested in the tutorial:

```
[package]
name = "guessing_game"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Novice <novice.coder@gmail.com>"]

[dependencies]
rand = "0.3.14"
```

Importing it in my code as:

```
use rand::Rng;
```

It gives this error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `rand`
 --> src/main.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use rand::Rng;
  |     ^^^^ maybe a missing `extern crate rand;`?
```

Am I missing something?

---

I added `edition = "2018"` as suggested:

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "guessing_game"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Novice <novice.coder@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
rand = "0.3.14"
```

Cargo build now gives:

```
$ cargo build --verbose
   Fresh libc v0.2.45
   Fresh rand v0.4.3
   Fresh rand v0.3.22
 Compiling guessing_game v0.1.0 (/home/bappaditya/projects/guessing_game)
 Running `rustc --edition=2018 --crate-name guessing_game src/main.rs --color always --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=4d1c2d587c45b4
c6 -C extra-filename=-4d1c2d587c45b4c6 --out-dir 
/home/bappaditya/projects/guessing_game/target/debug/deps -C 
incremental=/home/bappaditya/projects/guessing_game/target
/debug/incremental -L 
dependency=/home/bappaditya/projects/guessing_game/target/debug/deps -- 
extern rand=/home/bappaditya/projects/guessing_game/target/debug/deps/libra
nd-78fc4b142cc921d4.rlib`
error: Edition 2018 is unstable and only available for nightly builds of rustc.
```

---

I updated rust using `rustup update` and then added `extern crate rand;` to my main.rs. Now it's working as expected.

The program **runs** but in my vscode problems tab its still showing the error -

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `rand`
 --> src/main.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use rand::Rng;
  |     ^^^^ maybe a missing `extern crate rand;`?
```

Comment: the link you give have `edition = "2018"` in it. how can you miss it ?

Comment: I removed it, because it gave error -
error: Edition 2018 is unstable and only available for nightly builds of rustc.

Comment: @Bopsi Update your compiler.

Comment: The alternative, if you can't update your compiler, is to add `extern crate rand;` at the beginning of `main.rs`, as @LambdaFairy hinted in their answer.

Comment: extern crate rand still gives same error

Comment: Same error? If you remove the `edition` line and add the `extern crate` line, which error do you get?

Comment: I appreciate all the answers posted here but I still couldn't find a fix even after trying all the suggestions posted here.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The quick fix is to add

```
edition = "2021"
```

to your `Cargo.toml`, above the `[dependencies]` line.

### Explanation

There are three major *editions* of Rust: Rust 2015, 2018, and 2021. Rust 2021 is recommended for new code, but since Rust needs to be backward compatible, you have to opt in to use it.

In Rust 2015, you had to write an `extern crate` statement before using anything outside of `std`. That's where the error message comes from. But you don't have to do that in Rust 2018 or 2021 anymore, which is why setting the edition fixes it.

There are many more changes in Rust 2021; if you're interested, you can read about them in the [edition guide](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/edition-guide/introduction.html).

Comment: Now I am getting this error -
error: Edition 2018 is unstable and only available for nightly builds of rustc. I am udating the question

Comment: @Bopsi you can update your rust to 2018 via rustup update if you have the previous version installed. It is on stable now so you should not get any error after succesfull update. Here is the [reference](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2018/12/06/Rust-1.31-and-rust-2018.html)

Comment: after updating rust using rustup command, I added `extern crate rand;` in my main.rs. now its working

Comment: oh my god i was pulling my hair out trying to understand why any of my crates were being found. i'm now a rust-hater. but at least i'll finish my project