# How to build and deploy multiple contracts in NEAR protocol

Tags: nearprotocol

Currently the `cargo build` produces one WASM file like `contract/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/hello.wasm`. How can I produce multiple wasm binaries if my `contract` source tree contains multiple contracts, one per named Rust module?

My `Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "hello"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Why so difficult <argh@example.com>"]
edition = "2018"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "rlib"]

[dependencies]
near-sdk = "2.0.0"

[profile.release]
codegen-units = 1
# Tell `rustc` to optimize for small code size.
opt-level = "z"
lto = true
debug = false
panic = "abort"

[workspace]
members = []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although each contract still needs to go to its own crate, there is a cargo feature called [workspaces](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/cargo-and-crates-io/cargo-workspaces-for-multi-package-projects.html) that remove at least some of the repetitive boilerplate out of your contracts and you will have only one `Cargo.lock` file.

Split `contract` folder to multiple folders - let's call them 'token' and 'pool'.

On the the top contract folder have one workspaced `Cargo.toml`:

```
[profile.release]
codegen-units = 1
# Tell `rustc` to optimize for small code size.
opt-level = "z"
lto = true
debug = false
panic = "abort"

# Important security flag for the compiler,
# otherwise not present in optimised builds
# https://stackoverflow.com/q/64129432/315168
overflow-checks = true


[workspace]
members = [
    "token",
    "pool"
]
```

Then on each folder you have its own `Cargo.toml` that can have dependencies to other crates in the same workspace:

```
[package]
name = "nep9000_pool"
version = "0.0.0"

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/53985748/315168
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
near-sdk = "2.0.0"
nep9000_token = { path = "../token" }


[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "rlib"]
```

One `cargo build` in the root will build them all.

[Full example](https://github.com/miohtama/advanced-fungible-token/tree/master/contract).

Answer (score 4):

Yes. At the time of this writing we currently don't have anything similar to Truffle for deploying multiple contracts. We've been organizing multiple contracts into their own directories and then using a parent-level `build-all.sh` script that essentially runs a directory's `build.sh`.

An example would be the Chainlink repository here:
https://github.com/smartcontractkit/near-protocol-contracts

So for instance, one of the three contracts (`oracle` in this case) has its own directory with a `build.sh` script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cargo build --target wasm32-unknown-unknown --release
mkdir -p ./res
cp target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/oracle.wasm ./res
```

---

**Note**: when building smart contracts on NEAR you may see `cargo build…` commands that have more flags than are shown here. In this particular example, those flags have been moved to the `.cargo/config` file:

```
[build]
rustflags = ["-C", "link-args=-s"]
```

This helps for cross-platform compatibility, particularly with Windows.

---

Then at the parent level of the project there's a simple bash script that runs the child scripts like so:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cd near-link-token && ./scripts/build && cd ..
cd oracle && ./scripts/build && cd ..
cd client && ./scripts/build && cd ..
```

We do look forward to having a more robust deployment mechanism in the future.

Comment: Thank you! This example is super helpful. What are the techical requirements to produce a WASM binary for NEAR? I might want to try to stab the tool chain and see if I could avoid the excessive directories and extra toml files.

Comment: I found this super helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54843118/why-can-a-cargo-package-only-have-one-library-target

Comment: Looks like if binary instead of library would be used as a target it would be easy to build multiple contracts https://stackoverflow.com/a/36604610/315168

Comment: Moving the correct tick to the other answer, as it is gaining traction.