# NEAR and safe math on unsigned integers

Tags: nearprotocol

On Ethereum Solidity, a special library called `SafeMath` needs to be used when dealing with unsigned integer balance number. This is because of the [integer overflow exploits](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8551/security-review-checklist-for-a-smart-contract).

Does NEAR smart contracts written in Rust need similar mitigations? Or does Rust trap the oveflow automatically and panic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Rust has overflow checks enabled for debug builds, but disabled in optimized release builds. You can easily tweak it in `Cargo.toml` by setting `overflow-checks` in `profile.release` section:

```
[profile.release]
# ...
overflow-checks = true
```

NEAR core contracts [opt-into the paranoid mode](https://github.com/near/core-contracts/blob/215d4ed2edb563c47edd961555106b74275c4274/staking-pool/Cargo.toml#L18).

Even if you choose to use [`saturating_*`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.i64.html#method.saturating_add) or [`checked_*`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.i64.html#method.checked_add) methods explicitly, extra checks are still recommended.

Comment: Thank you. Opened an issue report against `create-near-app` https://github.com/near/create-near-app/issues/498