# Why `cargo build` immediately after `cargo check` recompiles some dependencies?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

What could be a possible reason for `cargo build` immediately after `cargo check` recompiling many (but not all) dependencies?

Cargo.toml

```toml
[package]
name = "greeter"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Near Inc <hello@near.org>"]
edition = "2018"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "rlib"]

[dependencies]
near-sdk = "3.1.0"

[profile.release]
codegen-units = 1
# Tell `rustc` to optimize for small code size.
opt-level = "z"
lto = true
debug = false
panic = "abort"
# Opt into extra safety checks on arithmetic operations https://stackoverflow.com/a/64136471/249801
overflow-checks = true

[workspace]
members = []
```

Comment: cf. https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2904#issuecomment-632292650

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cargo check` is not a build. It simply checks that your code would compile, but doesn't necessarily build anything. See [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-check.html) for more information.

So `cargo build` will need to actually build some crates, that where not built during `cargo check`. Other crates may need to be fully compiled to check (for example crates used in a `build.rs` script or by procedural macros), and where therefore already compiled when you ran `cargo build`.

Comment: After some investigating, it looks like `cargo build` adds `link` option to the `--emit=` argument for `rustc`, which results in it generating an `.rlib` file in the target directory, unlike in `check` case. `cargo check` seems to be doing all the work, but stopping at the last moment and doesn't save its work to disk :)